# JMeter asserting a response has been successfully downloaded

Tags: jmeter, response

I am using JMeter to test some of the functionality on my site. Through using the `Save Responses to a file` element, I have been able to successfully issue a request to download a pdf through JMeter. However, I am curious if there is an assertion to check that a file has actually downloaded (and if possible, is in the format I specified!). I know I can simply look at the file, but I'm hoping to make this more automated. I have checked "Save Successful Responses Only," but I want to ensure a response has actually been saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) for this.

Example code to check file presence, size and content type is below:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/downloaded/file");

//check file existence
if (!file.exists())
{
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "File " + file.getName() + " does not exist";
}

//check file size

long expectedSize = SampleResult.getBodySize();
long actualSize = file.length();

if (expectedSize != actualSize)
{
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "Actual file size differs from expected. Expected: " + expectedSize + " and got: " + actualSize    ;
}

//check content type

String expectedType = SampleResult.getContentType();
String actualType = file.toURI().toURL().openConnection().getContentType();

if (!expectedType.equals(actualType))
{
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "Response types are different. Expected: " + expectedType + " and got: " + actualType;
}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for more information on JMeter Assertions superpower.

Comment: while this was not the method I took, this would be an applicable way to check - in fact, I do something similar to clean-up the test and delete the file.